# What are the reasons that Office Store (App Source) published add-ins must reference Office.js on Microsoft's CDN?

Tags: office-js, office-addins, officedev

It would be good to understand why we are required to reference office.js from Microsoft's CDN to publish add-ins to the Office Store (App Source).

According to this [official GitHub documentation](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/develop/referencing-the-javascript-api-for-office-library-from-its-cdn.md)

“If you plan to publish your Office Add-in from AppSource, you must use this CDN reference. Local references are only appropriate for internal, development, and debugging scenarios.”

We recently experienced failures in office.js loading from this CDN in South Central US, Central US and West US data centres for a period of time while all resources we hosted loaded fine. Here's the results of an availability test we run every minutes on one our our App Source published add-ins. As you can see all resources we host ourselves loaded fine but the office.js on Microsoft's CDN failed. If we host office.js ourselves we can reduce this dependency risk but this would be against the requirement that App Source published add-ins must reference office.js via the CDN.

This shows a list of the failures to load in office.js from the CDN over a period of time and different data centres.

[image: List of failures loading office.js via CDN]

This shows the detail of the failure (which is consistent across all the failures listed in the previous screenshot).

[image: Detail of failure loading office.js via CDN]

Answer (score 0):

The official CDN usage guidance is to help ensure that add-ins are always pointing to the latest GA version of the library and that any essential updates are available at all times. There is no Official support for NPM package. However that should become an option at some point. We do provide a Nuget package for in-house add-ins. Regarding the CDN issue you are pointing to - could you provide more details on how you are setting up the probe test? Do you point to the generic CDN location or to one of the geo-locations? The CDN should provide fallback to the next closest region when any of the servers are not working. If that is not happening (or didn't happen on this occasion), it may be result of a network issue. How long did this outage last and are you facing similar issues now?

Comment: That particular outage lasted approx. 40mins and the issue is not present any longer. We've set up a probe test in Azure to the main index.html page of our web app (which is hosted in Azure as well). The probe test is run from 16 Azure data center locations and our web app is load balanced across 3 Azure data centers. During this particular outage out web app loaded fine as did the external dependency to jquery (which you can see in the screenshot from my original question) so there was definitely connectivity between data centers but failure on the generic office.js CDN.

Comment: Thanks. We'll see if this was a network blip or something more serious. In general, if one geo-location fails, the files should be served from next nearest location.